# How to pass data from child (mvc) window to parent window?

Tags: model-view-controller, parent-child, parent

How to pass data from child (mvc) window to parent window?
a few seconds ago|LINK

I have a situation where I need to pass some data from a child (MVC) page to parent window. But in this case the user does not need any interaction with the child window. The child window will simply open from the parent via a button click, to run a server-side process and return some code value to parent window and will need to close.

I am unsure how to pass data from a mvc page controller to a parent page and also how to close the child window itself..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may answer your question:

**parent window - parent.asp**

```
<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function openwindow() {     
   retval=window.showModalDialog("child.asp") 
   document.getElementById('passedChild').value=retval 
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form name=frm> 
<input name="passedChild" id="passedChild" type=text> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:openwindow()" value="Open Child"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**child window - child.asp**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<%
  '... i work in classic asp so can run asp here and then flow into JS for retrun
%>
// 
<script language="javascript"> 
function changeparent() {     
  window.returnValue="passed value" 
  window.close() 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:changeparent()" value="Change passedChild"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```